# How can I count most occuring sequence of 3 letters within a word with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a sample file like

```
XYZAcc
ABCAccounting
Accounting firm
Accounting Aco
Accounting Acompany
Acoustical consultant
```

Here I need to grep most occurring sequence of 3 letters within a word

Output should be

acc = 5
aco = 3

Is that possible in Bash?

I got absolutely no idea how I can accomplish it with either awk, sed, grep.

Any clue how it's possible...

PS: no output because  I got no idea how to do that, I dont wanna wrote unnecessary awk -F, xyz abc... that not gonna help anywhere...

Comment: the solution would be complicated due to partial matching - this is not word matching

Comment: That input file you posted doesn't look like CSV to me. Did you perhaps post just one column of your real CSV? Please post truly representative sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases (matches across lines, within fields, partial vs full, regexp vs string, etc...).

Comment: In your example `cou` would also occur 5 times. Bash/grep/sed is not really the best language for this kind of manipulation. The first question, what unique 3-letter codes exist' is hard to answer.

Comment: @EdMorton its a file i save as CSV .. just 1 column ;))

Comment: Then it's just a plain text file despite whatever extension you tack on the end of it. You could name it foo.html or foo.docx or anything else, that doesn't make it that type of file - the contents make it whatever file type it is and in this case it's just a plain text file since there are no separators in it that'd make it a CSV. Saying it's a CSV file is just confusing.

Comment: `3 letters words` - how are "3 letter words" obtained from normal words? Is `YZA` a "3 letter word" obtained from `XYZAcc`? And why isn't `cou = 5` in the answer? [my repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LankyDangerousAccess)

Comment: I wanted to post a beautiful solution but this is made impossible by someone who closed the question. This is frustrating.

Comment: Yeah the closes are coming much too fast and furious these days rather than teaching newbies how to ask a good question and they're harder to reopen now too.

Comment: @EdMorton: I would be very thankful to know who has the authority to reopen the question. I find it is a very interesting one.

Comment: Anyway, if someone is not happy with the fact the question was closed, I reopened the same question and posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724585/how-can-i-count-most-occuring-sequence-of-3-letters-within-a-word-with-a-bash-sc/59724586#59724586

Comment: @PierreFrançois, this is close to being re-opened (it's only 3 votes needed now, not 5, so only one short). When that happens, *one* of the questions should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: ...that said, I'm not sure this question *should* be re-opened (and, thus, that it was appropriate to re-ask). "How can a program that complies with specification X be created?" isn't asking a *specific, narrow* question, and it's generally well-accepted consensus that something that boils down to "please do my work for me" without a specific, narrow problem encountered during the course of the OP's attempts to help themselves is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to get started with what I THINK you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { stringLgth = 3 }
{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        field = $fldNr
        fieldLgth = length(field)
        if ( fieldLgth >= stringLgth ) {
            maxBegPos = fieldLgth - (stringLgth - 1)
            for (begPos=1; begPos<=maxBegPos; begPos++) {
                string = tolower(substr(field,begPos,stringLgth))
                cnt[string]++
            }
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (string in cnt) {
        print string, cnt[string]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k2,2nr
acc 5
cou 5
cco 4
ing 4
nti 4
oun 4
tin 4
unt 4
aco 3
abc 1
ant 1
any 1
bca 1
cac 1
cal 1
com 1
con 1
fir 1
ica 1
irm 1
lta 1
mpa 1
nsu 1
omp 1
ons 1
ous 1
pan 1
sti 1
sul 1
tan 1
tic 1
ult 1
ust 1
xyz 1
yza 1
zac 1
```

Comment: Hah, I'm getting closer, I did `1-NF`, but then `tolower` and looped `j=1;j<=length(s)-3` and `arr[substr(s,j,3)]++`. Reversed order of output in `END` and piped to `sort -r -n`

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative method to the [solution of Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59722345/8344060). It is less looping, but needs a bit more memory. The idea is not to care about spaces or any non-alphabetic character. We filter them out in the end.

```
awk -v n=3 '{ for(i=length-n+1;i>0;--i) a[tolower(substr($0,i,n))]++ }
            END {for(s in a) if (s !~ /[^a-z]/) print s,a[s] }' file
```

When you use GNU awk, you can do this a bit differently and optimized by setting each record to be a word. This way the end selection does not need to happen:

```
awk -v n=3 -v RS='[[:space:]]' '
    (length>=n){ for(i=length-n+1;i>0;--i) a[tolower(substr($0,i,n))]++ }
    END {for(s in a) print s,a[s] }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, sort and uniq):

```
sed -E 's/.(..)/\L&\n\1/;/^\S{3}/P;D' file |
sort |
uniq -c |
sort -s -k1,1rn |
sed -En 's/^\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)/\2 = \1/;H;$!b;x;s/\n/ /g;s/.//p'
```

Use the first sed invocation to output 3 letter lower case words.

Sort the words.

Count the duplicates.

Sort the counts in reverse numerical order maintaining the alphabetical order.

Use the second sed invocation to manipulate the results into the desired format.

---

If you only want lines with duplicates and in alphabetical order and case wise, use:

```
sed -E 's/.(..)/&\n\1/;/^\S{3}/P;D' file |
sort |
uniq -cd |
sed -En 's/^\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)/\2 = \1/;H;$!b;x;s/\n/ /g;s/.//p
```