# How can I count most occuring sequences of 3 letters within a word with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Indo Cheap has a sample file like

```
XYZAcc
ABCAccounting
Accounting firm
Accounting Aco
Accounting Acompany
Acoustical consultant
```

He needs to get the most occurring sequences of 3 letters within a word.

Output should be

```
acc = 5 aco = 3
```

He asks if that is possible in bash.

He says: "I got absolutely no idea how I can accomplish it with either awk, sed, grep.

Any clue how it's possible..."

Comment: So why didn't you edit [your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720777/how-can-i-count-most-occuring-sequence-of-3-letters-within-a-word-with-a-bash-sc#comment105595432_59720777)? Och I didn't see, it's someone else's question.

Comment: @KamilCuk, because it was [someone else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720777/how-can-i-count-most-occuring-sequence-of-3-letters-within-a-word-with-a-bash-sc) the OP is re-asking, in order to allow them to add an answer. Mind you, it still would have been the right thing to edit the question to fix its deficiencies and vote to re-open, rather than to ask a duplicative question.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I edited his question but the question was not reopened. I wonder why some guys close an interesting question, and I would like to know how we can prevent this behaviour.

Comment: If you want to argue that community consensus around what is and isn't too broad should be changed, the place to do so is [meta].

Comment: @PierreFrançois, ...it takes a while -- the first edit to a closed question puts it into the re-open queue for folks to vote on whether to reopen it. That process takes time. (I'm not in favor of re-opening, but that can be discussed in comments on the original question).

Comment: It would be helpful if the link your marked as a dup wasn't also *Closed*... (but this close was proper)

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely possible with bash, sed and awk, and here is how to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat sample | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr -s ' ' '\n'); do
  ll=${#line}
  for ((i = 0; i < ll - 2; i++)) ; do   # for each word
    echo ${line:i:3}                    # print all sequences of 3 letters
  done
done | 
  sort |                                # sort the sequences of three letters
  uniq -c |                             # count the sequences
  sed '/^ *1 /d' |                      # filter out the not repeated sequences
  sort -n -r |                          # most frequent sequences first
  awk -F ' ' '{print $2" = "$1}' |      # format output as asked
  tr '\n' ' '                           # put all results on one line 
echo                                    # add a new line at the end
```

And the ouput of the sample above is:

```
cou = 5 acc = 5 unt = 4 tin = 4 oun = 4 nti = 4 ing = 4 cco = 4 aco = 3
```

In case another format of output is wanted, we can easily adapt the code of the script according to the needs.

Comment: I'd suggest `echo "${line:i:3}"` with the quotes. We don't need the characters created by `$'\t*\t'`, for example, to cause the `echo` to emit a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: ...though really, to fix that case in a way that doesn't cause other problems you'd also need to follow the advice in [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).